# Is there a way to push a WIP branch and keep the changes uncommitted locally?

Tags: git

Here is my dilemma: I'd like to have all of my changes uncommitted locally because Xcode makes it much easier to see and jump between them, but I also want to commit the changes and push a WIP branch for others to review.

This is the workflow I came up with and I'm sure I could easily script it, but I'm guessing there is a better way:

1. Commit the changes to a WIP branch
2. Push the branch
3. Delete the branch
4. Recreate the branch
5. Cherry pick the commit with the `--no-commit` option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps 3 and 4 are not necessary. Change Step 5 to `git reset HEAD^ --soft` or `git reset HEAD^`. Both reset the current branch back to the previous commit. The former keeps the changes staged and uncommitted, and the latter keeps the changes not staged.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!